# CSV file from the SQL Server is out of format

Tags: sql, sql-server, email-attachments, sapb1

I am new to SQL Server and trying to send a CSV file as an email attachment to business users. Unfortunately, the file received is totally out of format. I have the following code and the table is from SAP B1. What would be the best way to resolve this?

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
          @profile_name = 'profile name',
          @recipients = 'recipent name',
          @subject = 'Test', 
          @query = 'select slpcode, slpname, memo, commission from dbo.OSLP ',
          @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
          @query_attachment_filename = 'Results.csv',
          @query_result_separator = ',', 
          @query_result_width = 32767,
          @query_result_header = 1,
          @append_query_error = 1,
          @query_no_truncate = 0
```

edit: Ideally, the data should be shown in only 4 columns as I have queried only 4 columns but instead this information is spread across columns A:N
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The sample data in the table looks as follows:
[Sample Data Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT3Lb.png)

and the result from my code shows up as follows:
[Final Result Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Vfx.png)
Thanks,

Comment: *the file received is totally out of format* what does this mean?

Comment: Hi @Stu, Ideally, the data should be shown in only 4 columns as I have queried only 4 columns but instead this information is spread across columns A:N. In addition to this, my second row just has '----------'

Comment: Hard to comment without seeing a sample of the actual data, does your data contain commas? Perhaps try concatting quotes around your varchar values eg presume slpname and memo are varchar columns.

Comment: Hi @Stu, Just added the sample data and the result I am currently getting to the original question. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: The attachment will be a text file, it's *its* content which needs to be ascertained, your results are not the text file but how it's been interpreted by a client application, possible Excel? You need to save the attachment and check it in Notepad.

Comment: As already mentioned, your CSV is probably fine, Excel is just interpreting it in the wrong way.

Comment: Try naming the file with a `.xls` extension, Excel may handle it better.

Comment: Hi, I tried naming the file as .xls and now all records are entered into the first column with no uniform spacing.

Comment: What is the table schema for `dbo.OSLP`? Seems like the `slpcode`, `slpname`, `memo` and `commission` columns may be fixed-width `char` or `nchar` types, as opposed to `varchar` or `nvarchar`.